# Subview height in UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I am working on an app where I had some ViewController without the storyboard & autolayout and I added other feature with the autolayout storyboard.

In the app, I have added storyboard & each viewcontroller has a header. 
I have to vary the height of the Header as per device size, so I created a class as below

```
@objc class CommonHeaderView: UIView {
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        //
        resetViewHeight()
        print("resetViewHeight is :\(self.frame.height)")
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        resetViewHeight()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    //MARK:- Reset Height as per device size
    func resetViewHeight()
    {
        self.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.widthAnchor, multiplier: CGFloat(115.0/320.0), constant: 0).isActive = true
    }
}
```

Each header in the storyboard inherited this class. This class works perfectly with the storyboard. for example, view height in iPhone 8 plus is 148.45

Now I am trying to use the same class in ViewController without storyboard (written in objective-c)

but view height always comes as 115.0

```
resetViewHeight is : 115.0
```

Please suggest how to vary the height of the headerview in without storyboard classes.

Any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: It appears to work fine for me... Running on iPhone 7, I get `resetViewHeight is :135.0`

Comment: @DonMag how did you try? Did you try in UIViewController sub class without storyboard. Please can you show your work

Comment: Yes, without storyboard. https://gist.github.com/DonMag/e4c09b18ca609aea4e6402ccc2f0b1a8

Comment: @DonMag thanks. let me check. Appreciate your help.

Comment: @DonMag can you please add your code in answer. I will mark as correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what the OP was doing wrong, but as per comments, here is a working example:

---

```
//
//  AppDelegate.swift
//
//  Created by Don Mag on 8/15/18.
//

import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        let testHViewController = TestHViewController()
        testHViewController.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        window!.rootViewController = testHViewController
        window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
        return true

    }
}
```

---

```
//
//  TestHViewController.swift
//
//  Created by Don Mag on 8/15/18.
//

import UIKit

@objc class CommonHeaderView: UIView {
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        //
        resetViewHeight()
        print("resetViewHeight is :\(self.frame.height)")
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        resetViewHeight()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    //MARK:- Reset Height as per device size
    func resetViewHeight()
    {
        self.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.widthAnchor, multiplier: CGFloat(115.0/320.0), constant: 0).isActive = true
    }
}

class TestHViewController: UIViewController {

    let hView: CommonHeaderView = {
        let v = CommonHeaderView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.backgroundColor = .blue
        return v
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.addSubview(hView)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            hView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            hView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            hView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),

            ])

    }

}
```